# Url Format: Empty Path

Tags: http, url, format

I have questions regarding the URL path format.

A url has a authority and a path. Now the question here is what is with an empty path (no path segments).

The following is considered.

1. The leading slash is part of the path. '/' is a path in http.//domain/
2. A empty path is actually a segment with a empty string as name "".

Those two assumption would lead to the following results:

A. http.//domain?query, http.//domain#fraction, http.//domain would be legal URL strings

B. The following domain path would be extracted for the given domains.

> - http.//domain -> segments = {}
> - http.//domain/ -> segments = {''}
> - http.//domain/a -> segments = {'a'}
> - http.//domain/a/ -> segments = {'a', ''}
> - http.//domain/a/b -> segments = {'a', 'b'}
> - http.//domain/a/b/ -> segments = {'a', 'b', ''}
> - http.//domain//// -> segments = {'', '', '', '', ''}`

Is this the correct interpretation?

PS: I used 'http.//' instead of 'http://' to avoid complains about illegal links.

Comment: I believe the last example should be `http.//domain//// -> segments = {'', '', '', ''}`, four slashes means four segments, not five.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is correct. You can read the [full URL specification (RFC 3986)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). Specifically [section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3).